# Bootstrap model box overflow scroll gap issue after close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal box, which is longer than the browser screen and has its own inner overflow scroll.
Upon 'close' of the modal box the browser doesn't re-adjust itself to be 100% width of screen, instead leaves a gap where the scroll bar was.

I can provide jsfiddle soon.

Thanks.

Comment: problem with width or height ?

Comment: Can you provide the fiddle?

Comment: upload your fiddle or plunker please.